# Boost uBLAS Matrix Reference

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, ublas, boost-ublas

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the address of an individual element of a Boost uBLAS matrix?

That is

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<char> bob(3,3);
some_function(&bob[2][2]);
```

Now, of course the second line won't work... but I'd like it to.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't using the address of the return value of the following operator be simpler? And independent of the matrix layout?

```
reference operator () (size_type i, size_type j)
```

For example:

```
some_function(&bob(2,2));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you? Could you be more explicit or explanatory? Sorry :-(

Comment: Fixed the indices in question in the question.

Answer (score 1):

by default, the inner representation of a matrix is a row major 1D array.

`some_function(&bob.data()[i*ncol+j]`   would work

Comment: By default in uBLAS? Which part of the Boost uBLAS specification indicates that this will work?

Comment: m.data() Returns a reference to the underlying dense storage. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/container_concept.htm#matrix. As for the storage, there are 2 types: row_major or column_major, default is row_major. I forgot where it was specified. I once called lapack routines with ublas matrix, as far as I am concerned, get the pointer of 1D array by m.data() works.